# Using REST and GraphQL in different parts of a single web app

Tags: javascript, rest, web, web-applications, graphql

I'm creating a web app and I'm wondering if it's possible to create it using both REST and GraphQl.  I don't mean I wan't to wrap REST in graphql.  It is a web app with a variety of functionalities and graphql would be best suited towards the blog portion of the app but we've already constructed the rest of it using REST.  Would it be possible/bad practice to use them for the respective parts of the app?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I don't see any problem with that. Just make sure to create a single API abstraction that would internally handle both cases so that the app itself is not concerned about that (in case you'll want to go all-in with GraphQL at some point).

Comment: Thank you so much for your response! Very much appreciated